# xcode side menus open on different tabs

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, xcode5.0.1

Each tab in my xcode project can have navigation/debug/utility menus open. If I close those menus on one tab, then switch to the next, they may be open. This is really frustrating! If I want the menus closed, I want them closed on all tabs. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tab:

(1) Copies the state of the tab/window from which it was cloned;

(2) Remembers and maintains its own state individually.

So, either create your new tab at a time when the panes are closed in the current tab (if that is the default you prefer), or else be willing to change the pane state when you switch to a tab if it isn't what you want *for that tab*.

(Or, don't use tabs, I guess.)

Also, it really helps to know the keyboard shortcuts for opening/closing the panes. When these are second nature, I find this is not such a big deal.

Comment: Yah I know the shortcuts for closing the panes. And I just created a behavior to close all panes. It's still really annoying to get used to :| Close all panes on a tab, switch to the next tab to make an edit and boom they all appear again. It's really jarring.

Comment: Behaviors do help a _lot_. Sorry I neglected to mention them in my response.